# How Do I Pass Props Using Single File Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Coming to Vue from React. For the most part there are a lot of similarities but passing `props` seems a little different. I couldn't find much documentation on how to do this using single file components. I import all my data for the app in `main.js`. I'm wondering how I can get parts of my data like `currentUser` for example, to `ResourceInfo.vue`? Again assuming these are all single file components. Do I need to pass it down through the `<App/>` part under `main.js` template option, then into `<resource-info></resource-info>` in `App.vue` then somehow into `ResourceInfo.vue`? I'd like to stay away from having to learn Vuex as well because I'm just starting out. Thanks!

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import ResourceInfo from '../src/components/ResourceInfo'
var db = firebase.database();
var auth = firebase.auth();

/* eslint-disable no-new */
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
        users: {},
        currentUser: {},
        quizzes: {},
        resources: []
    }
  },
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App, ResourceInfo },
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <resource-info></resource-info>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import ResourceInfo from './components/ResourceInfo'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    ResourceInfo
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

ResourceInfo.vue

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
var resourcesRef = firebase.database().ref('resources');

module.exports = {
  name: 'resource-info',
  data: function() {
    return {
      header: 'Before you build your quiz we just need some quick info.',
      resource: {
        type: '',
        title: '',
        url: '',
        desc: '',
        timesPassed: 0
      },
    }
  },
  firebase: {
    resources: resourcesRef
  },
  methods: {
    saveToFirebase: function() {
      resources.push({
        resource: this.resource
      })

      // Clear inputs  

      this.resource.title = '',
      this.resource.type = '',
      this.resource.desc = '',
      this.resource.url = ''

      console.log("Saving resource data...")

    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this.

#### Method #1 - using 'template'

If you want to pass props down from `main.js`, you need to edit the template there and pass the data down to `App` first:

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
  ...
  template: '<App :current-user="currentUser"/>'
  ...
})
```

...and in **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <resource-info :current-user="currentUser"></resource-info>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  ...
  props: ['current-user']
  ...
}
</script>
...
```

Then, `currentUser` will be available in `ResourceInfo.vue` (remember to add `props: ['current-user']`).

#### Method #2 - passing down via 'render' attrs

Render blocks allow defining attributes on the component you're rendering.

In your case, `currentUser` can be passed down like so:

```
var vm = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app', 
    data: function() { 
        return { 
            users: {}, 
            currentUser: {}, 
            quizzes: {}, 
            resources: [] 
        }
    }, 
    render (h) { 
        return ( 
            '<App />', 
            { attrs: { currentUser } } 
        ) 
    }, 
    components: { App, ResourceInfo } 
})
```

Then in `App.vue` you'll be able to access `currentUser` via props:

```
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import ResourceInfo from './components/ResourceInfo'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: ['current-user']
  components: {
    Navbar,
    ResourceInfo
  }
}
```

Now you can pass it further down to `ResourceInfo.vue` as you'd normally would (see below).

---

### Passing props in general

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <resource-info :current-user="currentUser"></resource-info>
  </div>
</template>
...
```

And add `props` in **ResourceInfo.vue**, like so:

```
<template>
  <pre>{{currentUser}} <!-- dumb example --></pre>
</template>

<script>
var resourcesRef = firebase.database().ref('resources');

module.exports = {
  name: 'resource-info',
  props: ['current-user'], // You can also do prop validation here
    ...
  }
}
</script>

...
```

You can read more about props [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props) :-)

---

Comment: No `prop` has to be passed from `main.js` to `App.vue`? When I do the above I get `Property or method "currentUser" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.` warning in the console. When I give `App.vue` a `props: ['current-user']` option as well the error goes away.

Comment: Can I also use the `currentUser` data in `ResourceInfo.vue` methods? Or can I only use it in the `<template></template>`

Comment: Yeah you can. It'll behave like a `data` property. So you can access it through `this`, for example, in **ResourceInfo.vue**: `methods: { foo () { console.log(this.currentUser} }`

Comment: Hm I'm getting a user object in the console but it's giving me undefined when I try to `console.log` it in `ResourceInfo`. Not throwing any errors though.

Comment: Read through your code again & **updated the answer**. Indeed, if **currentUser** is in **main.js** you need to pass it down to **App** first, then pass it further down to **ResourceInfo**.

Comment: I've double checked a few times and tried a couple different things. The prop is showing up in the devtools under the `App` and `ResourceInfo` component but the value is showing up as undefined. I can view the `currentUser` object in the Root component however.

Comment: can you make a jsbin with what code you have so far?

Answer (score 7):

@DanM. has already provided the answer, and I hope you managed to fix your `props` as per his guidance.

I am writing this answer so I can share my method of dealing with `currentUser` in my app (only for logged-in users). Here is my project structure (highly simplified for this answer):

Template: webpack, installed using `vue init webpack my-project` using `vue-cli`

**My app files:**

- **./main.js**: app entry file
- **./App.vue**: responsible for page layout, like header, footer, and route contents using `router-view`
- **./components/**: Common components like navbar, footer, etc.
- **./routes/**: Route components. I prefer to put it here instead of cluttering my components folder.
- and a lot more...

Code in my `main.js`: Just the standard code to define routes and bootstrap the app. Nothing special here.

Code in my `App.vue` - here is where `currentUser` gets fetched. Navbar also gets inserted, where I pass `currentUser` via `props`

```html
<template>
    <div class="app-container">
        <app-navbar :currentUser="currentUserInfo"></app-navbar>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import AppNavbar from "./components/app-navbar.vue"
import AppFooter from "./components/app-footer.vue"

export default {
    components: {
        "app-navbar": AppNavbar
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            currentUserInfo: {
                loading: true
            } // start with an empty object and modify later
        }
    },
    // ... all other code ...
    created: function() {
        // Ensure that this is a logged-in user. Or else redirect to login page
        this.$http.get("/api/currentUser").then(response => {
            // process response
            this.currentUserInfo = response
            this.currentUserInfo.loading = false
        }, error => {
            // user not found. exit the Vue app and go to login page (directly from server)
            // Refer to my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40194152/654825

            // Or alternatively, you can serve your App's index.html only for logged-in users. Then you will never reach here.
        })
    },
    // ... more code ...
}
</script>
```

Now receive `currentUser` in your component **./components/navbar.vue** as follows:

```html
<template>
    <div class="navbar">
        <!-- some code - branding, etc.. -->
        <div>{{currentUser.loading ? "Loading..." : currentUser.name}}</div>
        <!-- some more code - logout link, etc.. -->
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: ["currentUser"],
    // and more ...
}
</script>
```

Thats a lot to digest. I also use `vuex` extensively, which I did not show in the sample above as you did not want `vuex`.

I hope it helps to structure your app.

Comment: I was putting most of the logic in `App.vue` then refactored because it looked like that's what they were doing in the Hacker News example but they were also using Vuex I think. What are the benefits of putting it in `App.vue` as opposed to `main.js` and also what are 'router components' as opposed to 'common components'? Thanks so much for taking the time to write this out! Structuring an app properly is important to me!

Comment: Vue does not have any rigid conventions like Ember or Angular2. In my case, I decided to use **main.js** for only initializing the app, as it cannot have templates in it. My **App.vue**, which has the root template, is responsible for page layout - it has header, router-outlet and footer. I have two different folders for my components - 1. common ones like footer, header, data-store using vuex, etc. and 2. routable components (the ones inside route definitions). It is only a personal choice, thanks to the flexibility of Vue!

Comment: You can keep changing these folder conventions as your app grows. When you decide to create a new category of components, you only have to go back to your import statements in `.vue` files and fix the paths. It takes less than 5 min.

Comment: Once you get past the initial hiccups like passing data via `props` and figuring out how to store data centrally using `vuex` and make available to other components, your app will start growing very fast. After that, you can develop your own structure, the one that works best for your app.

Comment: Is there a way to easily reference properties in the data object? In `main.js` I could go `vm = new Vue...` and I would do `vm.aProperty` to reference it. In single file components I just have `module.exports = {}`. What is the best way to reference properties in the `module.exports` object?

Comment: The only way I know is to do `this.aProperty` inside component to access all kinds of data, whether it was passed through `props` or defined in `data` or `computed`. To access properties of a module from outside (from a parent component or from another unrelated component), you should either use parent-child communication or start using vuex.

Comment: Yes, but you will really like `vuex` once you get started. It is as useful as the vue-router. It manages all your data centrally, so your components can have a shared area. It is your data-store on the browser side, when your app is running.

Comment: Thanks. I've worked with Redux briefly and I think Vuex should be actually a little easier to pick up because it was built with Vue in mind. I'll start reading up on it now.