# How to create a 404 component in vuejs using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, http-status-code-404, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to vuejs and I'm working on my first project with vue. I'm just wondering how I will route to my `404.vue` component when the requested url is not found.

Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue-router redirect on page not found (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193634/vue-router-redirect-on-page-not-found-404)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In the routes declaration, I like to add this:

```
[
  ...  
  { path: '/404', component: NotFound },  
  { path: '*', redirect: '/404' },  
  ...  
]
```

Which will imply that if the user is navigated to a path which does not match any routes, it will be redirected to the "404" route, which will contain the "not found" message.

The reason I've separated it into 2 routes is so that you can also programmatically direct the user to the 404 route in such a case when some data you need does not resolve.

For instance, if you were creating a blog, you might have this route:

```
{ path: '/posts/:slug', component: BlogPost }
```

Which will resolve, even if the provided slug does not actually retrieve any blog post. To handle this, when your application determines that a post was not found, do

```
return this.$router.push('/404')
```

or

```
return router.push('/404')
```

if you are not in the context of a Vue component.

One thing to bear in mind though is that the correct way to handle a not found response isn't just to serve an error page - you should try to serve an actual HTTP 404 response to the browser. You won't need to do this if the user is already inside a single-page-application, but if the browser hits that example blog post as its initial request, the server should really return a 404 code.

Comment: How did you get this to work in the asyncData method inside a component?

Comment: If you don't want it to retain the path in the browser do: `{ path: '/404', alias: '*', component: NotFound,}`

Comment: This is bad for analytics/SEO. Search engine bots, Google Search Console, Google Analytics, etc. will not receive an actual 404 status code when the page is not found.

Comment: @torjinx what would be a SEO friendly option?

Comment: @HamishJohnson unfortunately I have not been able to find one yet... I'd be thrilled if someone else could chime in on this issue.

Comment: With a SPA app the server has already replied with 200 status code and then Vue loads and takes the user to the page. So you can't send a 404, as the server has already done a 200. You are best looking into server side rendering like Nuxt.js, as you probably can handle 404 that way.

Comment: You can redirect (using JavaScript) outside the single page application (to page with 404 status code provided by server). Otherwise, adding [noindex meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) may be search engine friendly solution.

Comment: Couldn't you eliminate the 1st route by giving the 2nd a name? (and using the by name `$router.push` overload).

Answer (score 27):

Now in Vue 3 `path: '*'` will not work. We have to use regex: `/:catchAll(.*)`

We can use directly instead of using `path: "*"`

```js
{
    // path: "*",
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFound,
}
```

or

```js
{
    path: '/404', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFound
},
{
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)', redirect:'404'
}
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544929/12206760)

Answer (score 18):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

The most generic one is to check if the path matches any route before navigation and if not redirect to the **Not found** page.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.matched.length) {
    next('/notFound');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cL7h4at/).

Comment: Unlike `path: '*'`, this approach catches navigation to named routes that don't exist, for example `:to="{ name: 'InvalidRoute' }"` or `$router.push({ name: 'InvalidRoute' })`. However it does add a tiny overhead to *every* request.

Answer (score 10):

After @g-wilson answer I went `{ path: '*', component: NotFound }`. Might be useful if you don't want to make redirect.

Comment: docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score -18):

For what I do is I give a class of `http-found` to the parent div all my component and I the mounted hook of the App.vue I check using jQuery or Javascript if there is any element with the class of `http-found` if not I redirect to my 404 page.

## App.vue

```
mounted(){
   if(!$('.http-found')){
     this.$router.push('/404')
   }
}
```

Comment: That is a strange mix of VueJS and jQuery. Most of the time you don't want to mix them.