# How to redirect user to a 404 page if a dynamic ID does exist in VueJS app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

how do I redirect a user to a 404 Not Found page if an ID does not exist?

I have a dynamic route like so:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/content',
    component: DataTable
  },
  {
    path: '/content/:NAS_ID',  <----what if there's an NAS_ID that does not exist? 
    name: 'datadetail',
    component: DataDetail

  },
  {
    path: '/404',
    component: NotFound
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/404'
  }
];
```

**How would I write a navigation guard for the invalid NAS_ID? Thank you.**

Comment: I think this is answered here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619407/how-to-create-a-404-component-in-vuejs-using-vue-router)

Comment: Don't think you can do this in your router file. You can certainly check the id in your `DataDetail` component, and manually redirect to `/404` if the `id` is not found.

Comment: Would a `beforeEnter` nav guard be doable? Not sure how I'd write it though. how would I check if the ID is invalid? Newbie here...sorta makes sense, but doesn't stick yet.