# How to redirect vuejs route when destination route is not avaiable?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a VueJS routing question.
I am trying to go to a dynamically generated route using the following code sample:

```
this.$nuxt.$router.push({ path: `/${documentId}/show`});
```

Bu in some cases documentId is not available and I get 'Request failed with status code 400', but instead I want it to be redirected to another path, say `/doesnotexist`.

I tried using [Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html), but couldnt get it to work.

My question is, can VueJS understand that a 400 code is received and help me to the redirect? Or I need to add more code to ensure the documentId is avaiable, and if not, then redirect?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193634/vue-router-redirect-on-page-not-found-404

Comment: Its not what I am actually trying to do, as it tries to redirect away from the app. I need to go just to another defined route.

Comment: Nuxt supports [SPA fallback](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#spa-fallback) for this. If you want to redirect to something other than your `404` page, then I think it makes sense to handle that locally in this component (redirect to the another path when `documentId` is undefined).

Comment: @tony19 thank you for the link and info. I decided to make another api call to make sure `documentId` is available and route accordingly afterwards based on the reply.