# Vue.js how to redirect to a common route if route isn't found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

This is **my simple routes.js file**.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import welcome from './components/welcome.vue';
import restaurant from './components/restaurant.vue';
import eatMe from './components/eat-me.vue';

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: welcome,
    name: welcome
}, {
    path: '/restaurant',
    component: restaurant
}, {
    path: '/eat-me',
    component: eatMe
}]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

export default router;
```

This works fine. But when if someone go to the url and type something else other than these 3 routes I want direct him to a common route says **page not found**. How to I achieve this using vue.js

Comment: `{ path: '*', component: something }`  or `{ path: '*', redirect: '/' }`  You'd think that be a so common use case they'd have it in their basic example or at least somewhere in the docs, but all they have is a link to this: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#parameters (from Advanced Matching Patterns) in the docs. I'm sure the order of your routes matter, put your fallback-route last.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**for Vue2**: At the bottom of your router configuration object use the router wild card syntax

```
{
    path :'*',
    component:NotFound
}
```

this will direct the user to the component **NotFound** if there is no matching route at the top, so your router config can be something like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import welcome from './components/welcome.vue';
import restaurant from './components/restaurant.vue';
import eatMe from './components/eat-me.vue';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: welcome,
    name: welcome
}, {
    path: '/restaurant',
    component: restaurant
}, {
    path: '/eat-me',
    component: eatMe
}, {
    path :'*',
    component:NotFound
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

export default router;
```

**for Vue3**: check the answer here from Aman
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817425/9128201

Comment: for Vue 3, please refer to Aman Dalmia's answer

Comment: @elliotching I did, thanks

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186073/7870587) answer, `*` doesn't work anymore for Vue 3. Simply replace:

```js
{
    path: '*',
    component: NotFound
}
```

with

```js
{
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    component: NotFound
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to redirect to url where appear url/page-not-found, you should create the path and then redirect to it when the user enter an url that not exists.

You should add this to your routes.js

```
{ path: '/page-not-found',
    components: {
        default: PageNotFound //Vue component
    },
},
{ path: '*', redirect: '/page-not-found' }
```

OR

```
{ path: '/page-not-found',
    component: PageNotFound //Vue component
},
{ path: '*', redirect: '/page-not-found' }
```