# "The specified key does not exist" for VueJS app deployed on deployed on S3 with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have deployed a VueJS app with S3 and CloudFront using Route53. It seemed like everything was working fine. I'm able to visit the site at `https://my-domain.com`, and I can navigate to different routes that I have set up with Vue router. However, when I try to access `https://my-domain.com/about` directly, I see the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>about</Key>
<RequestId>8371CJFJ48JM68239</RequestId>
<HostId>
/fQp7V6SuN0eDPgZpTroQrrxmfVQJTjXtroij56OIJONB56048OIaZDa4snkjc/Ygr/oZu0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here are the settings for my AWS resources:

### S3 Bucket

#### Properties

All properties are disabled (I don't have static website hosting set since I'm using https)

#### Permissions (Public)

Public Access Settings

All four options are set to false

Access Control List

Public Access: everyone can read and list objects

#### Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### CORS configuration

Nothing is set here

### Route53

I have a domain that has a hosted zone with 5 records:

- **mydomain.com**: A Record; Points to CloudFront distribution
- Default **NS** and **SOA** records that I have not changed
- ***.mydomain.com**: A record; Also point to CloudFront distribution for frontend subdomains
- **api.mydomain.com**: A record; Points to an ALB for backend API service

### CloudFront

Here are the `General` settings for my CloudFront distribution:

```
Distribution ID: 12356OIJSGSU9I
ARN: arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789012:distribution/ABCD1234
Log Prefix: -
Delivery Method: Web
Cookie Logging: Off
Distribution Status: Deployed
Comment: -
Price Class: Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)
AWS WAF Web ACL: -
State: Enabled
Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs):
*.mydomain.com
mydomain.com
SSL Certificate: mydomain.com (abc1234-1234-1234-1234-abcd1234)
Domain Name: abcd1234.cloudfront.net
Custom SSL Client Support: Only Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI)
Security Policy: TLSv1.1_2016
Supported HTTP Versions: HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0
IPv6: Enabled
Default Root Object: index.html
Last Modified: 2019-02-19 11:45 UTC-5
Log Bucket: -
```

I don't have any origin groups set up. I'm not sure if I need this but it sounds like it could help solve this issue.

I have also heard of AWS Amplify (https://console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/).

What settings can I change so that I can have non-root requests to my domain be routed to the VueJS app?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a typical issue with SPAs, because those routes like `/dashboard` are not real physical routes on the server. To fix this, just open your CloudFront distribution, go to the "Error Pages" tab, and create a Custom Error Response with the following settings:

[image]

This is essentially telling CloudFront to ignore a 404 error and just return an HTTP 200 response, and point to `/index.html`. Your SPA will handle any "page not found" errors internally via Vue Router. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193634/vue-router-redirect-on-page-not-found-404) might help with that.

Comment: I have solved this issue for s3 and then this, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue fixed by simply adding index.html in error document section in your s3 bucket -> edit static website hosting -> error document

[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VjOZ.png)

Comment: Weird, my application is still getting 404 with S3 "The specified key does not exist." with the error document specified as index.html