# Vue Routing and Regex Patterns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue and recently introduced a route with a parameter.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/:lang(^$|^es$|^pt$|^cn$)",
    name: "Home",
    component: Page,
  },
  {
    path: "/privacy",
    name: "Privacy",
    component: Privacy,
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFound,
  }
];
```

I want the route to trigger when one of the following conditions is met.

1. lang is **empty**
2. lang is either **es** or **pt** or **cn** but no combinations of those.

Everything else should go to the [NotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193634/vue-router-redirect-on-page-not-found-404) route

The regex I'm using above works on the javascript engine of [https://regexplanet.com](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html)

I tried all sorts and variations to make it work in Vue but to no avail so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the path you need is:

```js
path: "/:lang(|es|pt|cn)",
```

There's a routing tester here that uses the same library as Vue:

https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Make sure you're testing against `path-to-regexp` 0.1.7.

The problem is that the whole path gets converted to a RegExp, not just the bits in the brackets. So your `^` are never going to match anything. Try putting your original path into the testing tool to see how it compiles. The generated RegExp already contains its own `^` and `$` but they are relative to the whole path, not just the parameter you're trying to match.

Comment: Hi skirtle, 
this is definitely a start It does not allow the parameter to be empty tough.
```path: "/:lang(es|pt|cn)?"``` is what I'm using now - adding the **?** at the end makes it optional though.

I didn't know that regex and the **?** can be combined.

Comment: @NorbertHüthmayr The path I suggested should allow an empty value. I tried it myself in a Vue application and it seems to work fine. Note the `|` before the `es`.